# How to solve this div problem in react app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar

The navbar is leaving whitespace in the left and right after using Browser Router. What should I do?

Here's the code:

```
<div className="container my-3">  
        <BrowserRouter>       
        <Navbar title="TextUtils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode}/>
        <Alert alert={alert}/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<TextForm showAlert={showAlert} heading="Try TextUtils - Word Counter, Character Counter, Remove Extra Spaces " mode={mode}/>} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About mode={mode} />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
```

**Here are the images**

[Before using Browser Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw0Hr.png)

[After using Browser Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDwvs.png)

I tried many different css styling but the whitespaces are still there

Comment: can you open inspect element and check if browerrouter is occupying any space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't wrap your BrowserRouter inside that container div.

```
    <BrowserRouter> 
     <div className="container my-3"> 
     <Navbar title="TextUtils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode}/>
     <Alert alert={alert}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<TextForm showAlert={showAlert} 
        heading="Try TextUtils - Word Counter, Character Counter, Remove 
        Extra Spaces " mode={mode}/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About mode={mode} />} />
      </Routes>
     </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Do it this way and see.

Comment: I had tried before and I tried it now but the result is the same